# Trouble dissolving edges

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges

I made a weapon model in blender, I can't remember exactly when or how I ended up with these edges because I made the model a few days ago, however I came back to the model to use it as something to learn how to UV map with. That's when I noticed these edges on this face, the face is not meant to be separated like this, on the other side it appears normal but on the side with the bolt two edges appear, when I try to dissolve them nothing happens, if I completely delete them the whole face disappears.

[image]

In wire frame view in case it helps:

[image]

If I fully delete one edge it makes the faces invisible but the other edge stays, as shown here:

[image]

Alright so, started messing around with the model trying to figure out what went wrong, it appears that the un-dissolvable lines appear after putting a hole in the model using the Boolean difference modifier, no idea why or how to avoid this but thought this might help in finding a way to get rid of the edges.

**SOLUTION: Othoap Proto suggested that while in edit mode I select the faces that are separated by the two edges and then press "P/Seperate", by selection. The edges that where an issue then disappeared, all I had to do then was rejoin the two objects (Select the objects and press CTRl+J.) This worked for me and hopefully will for anyone else with the same issue.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There maybe extra vertex. In edit mode select all vertex and run "Remove Doubles" Or you will need to go corner by corner of the face and see it you need to merge any vertex.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that, but I just checked that and that does not appear to be the case, when I try removing doubles 0 verts are removed. However I noticed something I didn't mention earlier that might help come to a conclusion to why this is happening. When I delete one of the problematic edges the faces disappear but the other edge stays, added a image to the original post as an example.

Comment: On a test copy of this model. In Edit/Face mode select the face/faces in question and select "P/separate" then select this new model and hit "/" on the number pad to isolate just this. The go back in to Edit/Vertex mode and see is you can find a vert/ face folded back on it's self.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the vert/face folded back on itself. But when I separated the faces from the main part, the problematic edges vanished in object mode, I can still see them in edit mode but in object mode the face is now one, I don't know why I can still see them in edit mode but this solved the issue, thanks! :D